# Delaunay Triangulation for 3D Surface Data

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, tetgenlink

I want to do a Delaunay triangulation on scattered 3D surface data. *Mathematica* itself does it only for 2D through the command `DelaunayTriangulation[]`, which gives a triangulation for points in a plane. 
I also tried the [MathLink package "TetGenLink"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/tutorial/UsingTetGenLink.html#509267359), which can itself perform a Delaunay triangulation for three-dimensional data. The problem here is that `TetGenDelaunay[]` produces a triangulation through the inner region of the data, but I can't see how I can manage that the triangulation is only done for the surface (like what is done by MATLAB's `DelaunayTri` (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405732)).

Comment: So, performing a Tetrahedralization and keeping only the surface triangles isn't a valid solution

Comment: Would you mind supplying a bit of test data?

Comment: Access to some possibly relevant internal routines may be found at Demonstrations [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GeneralizedWatermanPolyhedra/) and [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Galactohedra/). This [one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagramOnASphere/) might also be useful.

Comment: @Daniel The last one doesn't work with Mathematica 9.  (It does with Mathematica 8.)

Comment: @Daniel & anyone else who might try the demonstration: It seems that the breakage is because of a change from a 0-based indexing to 1-based indexing in the tetgen library (not high level Mathematica) function `getFaces`.  It can be corrected by removing the `+1` from `getFacesFun@outInst` in the `ch` function in the demonstration source code.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the diagnosis.

Answer (score 10):

In **Version 10**, this can be done elegantly in one line:

```
SeedRandom[400]
pts = RandomReal[5, {400, 3}];
```

Then:

```
surftri = RegionBoundary @ TriangulateMesh @ DelaunayMesh @ pts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can look inside to see that only the surface triangulation remains:

```
HighlightMesh[surftri, {Style[0, Directive[PointSize[0.015], Blue]], Style[1, Thin, Black], 
  Style[2, Opacity[0.7], Cyan]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

As you state, `TetGenDelaunay` is for a tetrahedralization of the 3D space of the input data, and you'd then need to extract the surface triangulation. So for `TetGenDelaunay` there is no way around the tetrahedralization. (But I wonder if this is not also the case for `DelaunayTri`) TetGen is quite efficient, so maybe this is still an option. Perhaps, depending on the purpose of your computation, you could make use of `ListSurfacePlot` or `RegionPlot3D`.

In any case, here is how you'd extract the surface from the tetrahedralization:

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
data3D = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 3}];
in = TetGenCreate[];
TetGenSetPoints[in, data3D];
out = TetGenTetrahedralize[in, ""];
coords = TetGenGetPoints[out];
(* issue in TetGen interface, thus + 1 *)
surface = TetGenGetFaces[out] + If[$VersionNumber < 9.0, 1, 0];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[surface]], Boxed -> False]
```

[image: surface tetrahedalization]

To set vertex colors you can use:

```
values = Sqrt[Total[coords^2, {2}]];
cf = ColorData["TemperatureMap"];
vc = Developer`ToPackedArray@(List @@@ (cf[#] & /@ values));
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
 GraphicsComplex[coords, Polygon[surface], VertexColors -> vc]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: surface tetrahedalization, with colors]

Comment: @J.M. thanks for fixing my poor spelling!

Comment: You're welcome! I initially considered using TetGen too, but I got bogged down in figuring how to pick out the outermost polygons. I didn't know it was this easy!

Comment: @J.M. do you think the documentation would benefit from such an example?

Comment: Looking around, surface triangularization seems to be a quite common task, so yes, I think including such an example in the docs would be nice.

Comment: Hi, it's in `SystemFiles/Links/TetGenLink`

Comment: @ruebenko in V9 this solution produces rather different output?

Comment: @YvesKlett, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Isn't the boundary of the Delaunay tetrahedralization just the convex hull of the data, which can be found in much more straightforward ways?